# Problem updating truffle framework

Tags: truffle, solc, upgrading

I have problems updating truffle. I run the command "truffle --version" and i got truffle version 4.0.1 and solc version 0.4.18. So i wanted to upgrade to 4.1.6 which is the latest version. I run "sudo npm uninstall -g truffle" and then i run the command "sudo npm install -g truffle". After that i run "truffle version" and i got again 4.0.1 and solc 0.4.18. Does anyone know why i can not update to latest version? Basically i am intrested in updating solc version to latest 0.4.22 but after some search i found out i have to update truffle in order to update solc compiler.

Fixed: After i restarted the pc, truffle was updated. Also as Med Mansour commended below maybe a restart wasn't neseccary and it was just needed to close the cmd or terminal and open a new one.

Answer (score -1):

you should go to the general `node_modules` folder and then to the `truffle` folder and from there run the `npm install solc@0.4.22`. that way truffle will use the new compiler even if it will not display it when running `truffle --version`.

It worked for me and is probably the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know if it works, because after i restart the pc truffle was updated. It was a stupid mistake not to think to restart the pc, but i didn't thought it was necessary.

Comment: yes it shouldn't be necessary, but maybe you just needed to close the cmd or terminal and open a new one, happened to me on windows before.

Comment: Modifying any subdependency or any code within node_module is a dirty hack and should never happen as any update of the dependencies would remove the modifications. 

If there's a bug due to bad dependency implementation it should be mentioned to maintainers in an issue, and if not maintained, create a fork of the dependency.

Comment: @Asone This happened due to truffle not working straight with updating solc. This answer is way old and was originally proposed to me by a contributor on the GitHub issue concerning this same issue.